# inline-block aligning vertical by default

Tags: html, css-float, css

I am making a social media bar at the bottom of a website and would like for all of the social media icons to line up horizontally. I have a parent div that encases the social media icon divs. I am trying to not only center the parent div on the page but also center all of the social media icons within that div.

When I use the inline-block tag all of my social media icons align vertically in the middle of the parent div. I have also tried floating them but cannot seem to figure out how to center them with that format either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div id="socialcontainer">
    <div class="facebook"><a href="https://facebook.com/"></a></div>
    <div class="twitter"><a href="https://twitter.com/"></a></div>
    <div class="google"><a href="https://google.com/"></a></div>
    <div class="linkedin"><a href="https://linkedin.com/"></a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#socialcontainer {
width: 100%;
margin: 0px auto;
text-align: center;
}


.facebook a {
height:64px;
width:64px;
display: inline-block;
background: url('../img/socialicons/facebook_dark.png');
}

.facebook a:hover {
background: url('../img/socialicons/facebook_active.png');
}

.twitter a {
height:64px;
width:64px;
display: inline-block;
background: url('../img/socialicons/twitter_dark.png');
}


.twitter a:hover {
    background: url('../img/socialicons/twitter_active.png');
}

.google a {
height:64px;
width:64px;
display: inline-block;
background: url('../img/socialicons/google_dark.png');
}    

.google a:hover {
    background: url('../img/socialicons/google_active.png');
}

.linkedin a {
height:64px;
width:64px;
display: inline-block;
background: url('../img/socialicons/in_dark.png');
}

.linkedin a:hover {
    background: url('../img/socialicons/in_active.png');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the `inline-block` to the DIV tags that enclose the a tags like the below:

`#socialcontainer > div{ display: inline-block;}`

Comment: That worked! I cannot believe I did't think about that! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry this if my first time using the site!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: add to the CSS of each enveloping `<div>` the following attribute: `display:inline`.

Comment: Should I remove the div that is `display:inline-block` from the enveloping (social media class) divs? And you you say enveloping you mean the individual social media classes correct? When I make that change the social media bar with the display-line the bar no longer appears on the site. Any reason why?

Comment: @HunterSneed If the bar disappears, it's probably inheriting a `display:none` proper from a parent element.  You should probably consider using a `table` element instead of the nested `div`s.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this modified css to your html,

```
#socialcontainer {
position: relative;
width: 256px; // 64 * 4
left: 50%;
margin: 0px auto;
margin-left: -128px;
text-align: center;
}

.facebook, .twitter, .google, .linkedin { width: 64px; float: left; }

.facebook a {
height:64px;
width:64px;
display: inline-block;
background: url('../img/socialicons/facebook_dark.png');
}

.facebook a:hover {
background: url('../img/socialicons/facebook_active.png');
}

.twitter a {
height:64px;
width:64px;
display: inline-block;
background: url('../img/socialicons/twitter_dark.png');
}


.twitter a:hover {
    background: url('../img/socialicons/twitter_active.png');
}

.google a {
height:64px;
width:64px;
display: inline-block;
background: url('../img/socialicons/google_dark.png');
}    

.google a:hover {
    background: url('../img/socialicons/google_active.png');
}

.linkedin a {
height:64px;
width:64px;
display: inline-block;
background: url('../img/socialicons/in_dark.png');
}

.linkedin a:hover {
    background: url('../img/socialicons/in_active.png');
}
```

Comment: When I applied this code the parent div is no longer in the center of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a new div inside container to control the position as you want inner-content to be center horizontal
I think it is the easiest solution see my JS bin

here is the [code for the solution i propose](http://jsbin.com/usolel/4/watch)

Comment: The JS worked but is there any way to complete this without the utilization of JS?

Comment: It is working with just css, no JS, also i just had wrong images paths set......Please view it again